# Move row from column to another one

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if it was possible to move a row from one column to another one. I have three columns, `image_one`, `image_two`, `image_three` and when the user uploads the images, I am showing it to him/her right after and he can remove the image if he wants. Finally I just insert the images.

What I want to do is if the user removes image one and then uploads two and three, I would like to move the images to image one and two so that image one won't be empty.

Is it possible to do this way using maybe a select statement?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. However, if your normalise your tables, you won't have this problem: instead of just having a table `user`, have table `image_upload` as well, with a foreign key to `user`.

Comment: @halfer I would love it if you show me how to do it. I just realized this prob at the very end.

Comment: What particularly are you stuck on? "How to do it" is rather broad, given that I don't know how you've implemented what you have already. Just create a table `image_upload` thus: `id` (integer, primary key, auto increment), `user_id` (integer, not null), `path` (varchar, not null), `created_at` (timestamp, not null). Create that, and then insert a row when you upload an image and delete a row when you delete an image. (Bonus points for adding a relational constraint on the foreign key, but it's not critical). Let us know how you get on!